# How to generate typescript definitions from javadoc?

Tags: typescript, javadoc

I've recently discovered [YUIDocs](http://yui.github.io/yuidoc/), which has a parsing function which turns the docs into json.  Is there a similar tool that can convert javadocs (properly commented javascript) into a typescript definition?

Comment: Looks like I'm needing the fictitious jsdoc-to-typescript dependent upon https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdoc-parse.

Comment: How about [this](https://github.com/vojtechhabarta/typescript-generator)?